# I can't get my div to stay inside my header when I make my window smaller

Tags: html, css, header, nav

I wanted to include a nav bar in my header, but in order to make sure it wouldn't overlap with my heading when I shrink my window, I made my heading into a block object, and it fixed it.

Now I want to move my nav bar to the right of the header, but when I use float, or position: relative or absolute, I find that my nav goes out of the header when I shrink my window or overlaps. I don't know what technique I could use to make sure my header grows to cover all my code inside it when I shrink my window.

EXAMPLE:
This is all the content in my header:

```
<header>
       <div class="header-div">
         <h1 class="header-text">WELCOME TO THE <br> HAUNTED MANSION!</h1>
       </div>

       <nav class="home-menu">
         <ul class="home-ul">
            <li class="home-btn"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="home-btn"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li class="home-btn"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
    </header>
```

GOAL:
[That's the position I want for my nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wWj7.png)

When I use position relative or absolute my nav gets cut off when I shrink my window:

```
nav.home-menu{
    position:relative;
    left:600px;
    bottom: 70px;
}
```

Using float my nav leaves the header:

```
nav.home-menu{
    float: right;
}
```

Please tell me what the best way to move this nav is in order for it to be responsive when I move it.

Comment: That's going to be really, really small on a smartphone. I would consider placing your links/buttons below the heading for smaller devices.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox, its modern and useful.

Don't use my code, inspire yourself from it, but improve it!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaVaRP

```
   .header-div {
      width: 60%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: red;
    }
    .home-ul li {
     display: inline;
    }
    .home-ul li .header-text {
      float: left;
    }
    .home-ul li a {

      display: flex;
      margin-top: 4%;
      padding: 8px;
       color: blue;
      float: right;
    }
```

Comment: OP is looking for the links to be to the right of the `h1`.

Comment: oops, reload the link it should be ok now (I didn't save the codepen)

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I'll definitely look into flexbox. I'll make sure I study the concept behind it, and that I'm able to apply it on my own, at will :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just replace your fonts and images to make it scary again! :D

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 10rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: gray;
    border-bottom: solid 4px red;
  }

  header,
  .header-div,
  .header-menu {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .header-div,
  .home-menu {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: red;
  }

  .header-div {
    line-height: 3.6rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }

  .home-menu {
    float: right;
  }

  .home-ul {
    list-style: none;
  }

  .home-btn {
    float: left;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 8rem;
  }

  .home-btn > a {
    display: block;
    background: black;
    color: red;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin: 2.5rem 0.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 red;
    border-radius: 0.75rem;
  }
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="header-div">
     <h1 class="header-text">WELCOME TO THE <br> HAUNTED MANSION!</h1>
   </div>

   <nav class="home-menu">
     <ul class="home-ul">
        <li class="home-btn"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="home-btn"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="home-btn"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
</header>
```